# qml2 Non-existent attached object ImageParticle

Tags: qt, qml

When I try to build a particle system by using ImageParticle in qml2, the compiler gives this error:

```
Non-existent attached object 
         ImageParticle:{ 
        ^
```

Here is the part of my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0
Item {
id:particle
anchors.fill: parent
Rectangle{

anchors.fill: parent
ParticleSystem{
    id:petalParticleSystem
}
ImageParticle:{
        source:"image/Petal.png"
        system:petalParticleSystem
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you have a colon in

```
ParticleSystem{
```

and

```
Rectangle{
```

but you do have one here?

```
ImageParticle:{
```

That's what the error message means, I think.